# ASP.NET Web API 2 ViewModels?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I am new to ASP.NET Web API (to API at all). My question is if there is something similar to the ViewModels (I guess in API they won't be called ViewModels even if such a thing exists) in ASP.NET MVC or do I have to use the database models from my DataAccess layer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My question is if there is something similar to the ViewModels

Yes there is and it's same as in MVC. Name `ViewModels` doesn't matter as it's called by many name like `DataModel` or `Model` or `DTO`. But in essence it's a `Data Transfer Object (DTO)` which doesn't have or maintain any state.

Again, you should be having separate viewmodel for your corresponding entities; and should include your data validation(s) logic in model object. Which also adds an layer of abstraction over your actual entity as to what specific data you want to transfer to your client

Comment: Great point and probably the answer the OP was looking for.  A `ViewModel` is really just another name for the slice of data that is exposed to the user.

Comment: @john, as mentioned that doesn't really matter

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly have view models in WebAPI.  You can return any object you like from your API methods.

In fact, I'd recommend returning view models specifically in an API scenario because you don't want to also serialize any of the extra properties that may be attached to data access objects, particularly framework-generated ones.  Having simple POCOs for your API responses gives you full control over the resulting data received by clients.

Comment: @john: If you like, sure.  I've generally been comfortable with the term "view models" because, while the result isn't a "view" in the ASP.NET MVC Framework class definition, it is a "view" in the pattern definition because it's ultimately what gets exposed by the application to the consumer.  Ultimately the terminology is up to you and your team/domain/etc.  Just make it clear and consistent and you're good.

Answer (score 0):

The choice you make here depends on your design and relative application complexity.  There is a small cost in development to map between domain models and business models.  However, I do suggest creating a view model for your api layer for the following reasons:

- It defines an explicit contract for your API
- If your domain model changes, it doesn't impact your users
- You can version your API without impacting your domain layer